# how i deploy kie-drools-wb 6.2.0 with tomcat7?

Tags: java, drools

I follow bellow link but not success to integrate kie-drools-wb 6.2.0 with  Tomcat-7. can anyone help me to resolve my problem?

visit http://www.tagwith.com/question_505795_setup-drools-kie-execution-server-credentials

Answer (score 3):

Better to follow this document.This will give you a clear idea regarding to the installation of the KIE workbench installation along with the tomcat.

http://blog.athico.com/2014/04/deploying-kie-drools-wb-on-tomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did.

- I deployed the "kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7"
  war file into tomcat 8 server.
- Then open the README file and follow each and every step religiously.
  At the end of it i had the drools work bench up and running.